# More control over iPhone notification area for 3rd party calendar application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing a calendar application for iOS 5.0+ and would like alarms/notifications to work like the default Calendar application.  What control, if any, do I have over these items **without jail-breaking** (in regards to the pull-down notification area):

1. Show items coming up soon, BEFORE the alarm goes off (the calendar app shows items tomorrow, maybe a few days in the future).
2. When my items do show up in the notification area, have the date/time it shows on the right side be the time of the event, not the time of the reminder/alarm for the event.

If not possible to do #2 above, it is very misleading, the user will think the event is "now" but really that was just the alarm time.  So if not possible, can I:

Keep the popup style notification with sound, but **never** have my items show up in the notification center.

I know I can clear items from the notification center when my app runs, but if the user selects the "close" option or just ignores them, my app doesn't run, so doesn't get a chance to remove the item -- and the user might be in that misleading state.

If none of the above is possible, I suppose I'll include the event time in the text, but geesh my app is going to suck compared to the default Calendar app when it comes to some things that Apple just will not let us do.  Of course my users will not understand either, why some apps can do these things, but mine cannot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no real way for you. only apple can do it

1. could maybe be achieved with scheduling another notification before the final one
2. no way I can see

Comment: sorry, but I dont see any other way -IMHO